# Edit xml file C++

Tags: c++, xml, fstream

my program have an xml file (called "registro.xml") where the program write the output result and get the input data that are already store.
Parse the data from the file is simple using a library like TinyXml, but i've a problem for the output:
The file mustn't be overrite by the program but the data mustn't write a the end of the file:
Example:

registro.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  <FATTURE>  <fattura IDFattura="1" Ditta="ditta5" Importo="132.20" Emissione="26/01/2015" NumeroRate="2">
<rata Scadenza="20/08/2019" Importo="100" />
<rata Scadenza="12/08/2018" Importo="32.2" /> </fattura> </FATTURE>
```

The program should take a new object called "fattura" and write in "registro.xml". 
The problem is if load the ofstream in this mode `std::ofstream file("registro.xml",std::ios::app|std::ios::binary);` the program can write only after `</FATTURE>` but this isn't correct and too if I asked the program sometihng like `file.seep(-11)` is impossibile to write in the correct position.
Instead if i load the file in this mode: `std::ofstream file("registro.xml",std::ios::binary);` the file is overrrite.
Is possible to edit the file not at the end but before the line `</FATTURE>` without delete the other data in the file?

Comment: If I understood you correct you need something like here
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303845/how-to-use-libxml2-to-modify-an-existing-xml-file][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303845/how-to-use-libxml2-to-modify-an-existing-xml-file

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what about TinyXml but you can read and write with Boost.PropertyTree http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/property_tree/parsers.html#property_tree.parsers.xml_parser